# R Using ifelse inside dplyr filter

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, filter

In my chart I would like to show data from previous month depending on what month we currently have. I have developed following piece of code for this purpose:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(mesic = month(create_date)) %>% 
  filter(ifelse(month(now()) > 1, mesic == month(now()) - 1, mesic == month(now()) + 11))
```

But the filter somehow does not apply (I end up with empty dataset). Is it not possible to use ifelse inside the filter?

Comment: Try `case_when()` instead of `ifelse`.

Comment: Could you share your data using `dput()`, or provide some example data?

Comment: I used case_when and it works. Thanks! @Julian 
`data %>% 
  mutate(mesic = month(create_date)) %>% 
  filter(
    case_when(
      month(now()) > 1 ~ mesic == month(now()) - 1,
      month(now()) == 1 ~ mesic == month(now()) + 11
    )
  )`
Still my question would be the same: Why is ifelse not compatible in the original example, anyone knows?

Comment: I assume it is related to the vectorized nature of ifelse. You can post your solution not as a comment, but as an answer and mark it (after 24hs) as solved ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to the problem is to use case_when instead of ifelse (credits to @Julian):

```
data %>%
  mutate(mesic = month(create_date)) %>%
  filter(
    case_when(
      month(now()) > 1 ~ mesic == month(now()) - 1,
      month(now()) == 1 ~ mesic == month(now()) + 11
    )
  )
```